# Create gif animation

Tags: c#, .net, animation, gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create an animated gif in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net)

I would like to be able to created animated gif files from other file type (jpeg, gif, etc.) with c#. is there a library (doesn't have to be free) that can help you manipulate gif files through C#?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/NGif.aspx

Comment: I've tried this one - it doesn't work on gif files properly, and you can't set changing delays. it can, however, do the simple join of several static images into an animated gif with a fixed delay.