# Setting the framerate of an animated gif from GifBitmapEncoder

Tags: c#, gif

I'm trying to create an animated gif in C# using `GifBitmapEncoder` from a selection of `BitmapFrame` objects, but I'd like to be able to set the framerate myself.  Is there any way to do this?  If there isn't, what will it set to automatically (so that I can know how many frames I need to put into the encoder)?

Comment: Not supported.  No lack of alternatives that google easily.  Possible duplicate of [how to create an animated gif in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net)