# How to create an animation in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8, animated-gif

Does anyone know how to create an animated gif using c# in windows phone ?
i want to use more than one JPEG to create an animated gif or Other animated format
but I don't know how to do

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net.

Comment: this link does not solve the purpose