# saving C# winforms Panel or PictureBox with animated elements to gif file?

Tags: c#, winforms, animated-gif

How to save C# winforms Panel or PictureBox with animated elements to gif file?
I also tried to do it like this

```
pictureBox2.Image.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "1.gif"),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

but it save just static image without animation.

Comment: Winforms is not capable of creating animated .gif files.  You'll need to shop for another library that does support it.

Comment: Try [GifBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapencoder(v=vs.90).aspx)!

Comment: this might help: [There is a built in .NET class which will encode GIF files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598294/5887293)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/saving-an-animated-gif-image-with-c-in-windows-forms/). The Bumpkit library he uses is open source, so you can just include the file you need in your solution.