# Create a Gif File , but is not loop

Tags: c#, gif

I use the GifBitmapEncoder Class to Create a gif File. Create Success , But it is not Loop.

my code：

```
private string[] _files = null;
private void CreateGifFile()
{
    if (_files != null && _files.Length != 0)
    {
        GifBitmapEncoder gEncoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
        _files.ToList().ForEach((a) =>
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(a);
            var src = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap
            (
                    bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()
            );
            gEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
        });

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream ("1.gif", FileMode.Create))
        {
            gEncoder.Save(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: What do you mean *it does not loop*? How many items are in _files?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I think OP means that the resulting `.gif` file should repeat the animation endlessly.

Comment: So, how did you fix it?

Comment: I answer from other Questions, the link is below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111224/8917485