# Search for Memory Leak in Gif-from-jpgs program

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

I wrote a C# program that takes in a directory name, iterates through the files in it in batches of 100, and outputs gifs.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GifBitmapEncoder encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();

        int i = 0;
        int filei = 0;
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(args[0]).OrderBy(s => s))
        {
            i++;
            AddFileToBitmap(encoder, fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Added file {0:000}: {1}", i, fileName);

            if (i % 100 == 0)
            {
                string outFile = string.Format("output{0}.gif", filei);
                Console.WriteLine("Saving to file: {0}", outFile);
                SaveGif(encoder, outFile);

                filei++;
                encoder.Frames.Clear();
                encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
                GC.Collect();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }

    static void AddFileToBitmap(GifBitmapEncoder encoder, string fileName)
    {
        using (Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(fileName))
        {
            BitmapSource bitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                img.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
        }
    }

    static void SaveGif(GifBitmapEncoder encoder, string fileName)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, memory usage starts at ~1MB, grows to ~800MB for the first 100 images; drops to ~400MB and grows to ~1.2GB for the second 100 images; drops to ~800MB and crashes with an out of memory error for the remaining 30 images.

I assume there is a memory leak somewhere, but I can't find it.  `GifBitmapEncoder`, `BitmapSource`, and `BitmapFrame` are not `IDisposable` so I can't dispose any of those, and I don't see any other variables I use that could be.  Maybe `img.GetHbitmap()` which returns a `IntPtr`?

Any thoughts?

I got the meat of my code from [how to create an animated gif in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net).

Comment: If you profile your application you can see exactly what is being allocated -- it will remove all doubt and saves us from pretending we're a compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        using (Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(fileName))
        {
            IntPtr hBitmap = img.GetHbitmap();

            BitmapSource bitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                hBitmap,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        }
```

The documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx

> You are responsible for calling the GDI DeleteObject method to free
>   the memory used by the GDI bitmap object. For more information about
>   GDI bitmaps, see Bitmaps in the Windows GDI documentation.

Comment: Oddly, this appears to be the solution looking at Task Manager, but I still hit the `OutOfMemory` exception in the same spot, despite only using 167MB of RAM.

Comment: I also noticed it only seems to do this after the last frame is added.  And due to a bug in my code, I wasn't even saving the last gif at all, so it's throwing the error when trying to exit the program.

Comment: More accurately, it's failing when exiting the `foreach` loop on the file names.

Comment: And I just figured it out.  There's a hidden file called thumbs.db that I wasn't filtering out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
encoder.Frames.Clear();
encoder = null;
GC.Collect();
//GifBitmapEncoder derives from DispatcherObject which has finalizer
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
//then create a new instance
encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
```