# Is it possible to create animated GIF using only .NET/C++ built in libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, animated-gif

I'm finding a way to create an animated GIF in `.NET or C++/CLI`. Beacause I'm working for a commercial product, I need to avoid 3rd party libraries as much as possible. Therefore, some useful 3rd party libraries likes **NGif, Bumpkit, ImageMagickare** are not good options due to license concern.

I tried `GifBitmapEncoder` class in .NET to create animated GIF with:

```
animatedGIF.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(myImagesList));
animatedGIF.Save(outputStream);
```

But all it does is to save the last image to .gif file not the whole images list for animated GIF.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to make animated GIF with built in libraries/framework?
- If it is impossible to do so, can you please recommend me any safe to use 3rd party libraries for commercial product without worrying about license problem?
- Since I have never used 3rd party library in commercial product before, is there anything that I need to take note before using such 3rd party libraries?

Your help is very much appreciated.

**Edit 1:**
I had searched through all the advices of this question: [how to create an animated gif in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net). before I posted this question.

However, the class `GifBitmapEncode` .NET built in library doesn't solve the problem as I mentioned above. Other 3rd libraries are not safe to use due to license concern as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Try looking at this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create an animated gif in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net)

Comment: Hi @EdwinJ85 and xMRi I had read that question before I posted my question but those advices don't solve my problem since I have to worry about license problem. Please see my Edit 1 for more detail.